# How to remap a key using AHK to open and close Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, scripting, autohotkey

I am new to AHK and been trying to fidget around with it for quite some time, what I need to do is open a specific profile of Google Chrome when a key is pressed and if it's open close it when the same key is pressed. I tried many things but can't quite figure out how to do it, this is what I have right now.

```
PgDn::
    Process, Exist, chrome.exe
If ErrorLevel <> 0
    Process, Close, chrome.exe
Else    
    Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 1"
return
```

This opens up the chrome to a profile I want but when I close press the button again it closes any and every chrome window open. I understand that's because I close the chrome.exe process, I cannot figure out how to close that specific profile.

Ultimately what I want to do is when the Page Down key is pressed

```
If Chrome Profile 1 is not opened, open it.
If Chrome Profile 1 is minimized, maximize it.
and if Chrome Profile 1 is opened and maximized, close it.
```

I would really appreciate if someone could assist with this.

Answer (score 1):

AHK's [`Run` command](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) has a parameter named: `OutputVarPID`.

you can use this to store the process id of the started chrome instance in a variable, which you can then pass to your `Exit` command.

Comment: Hi Cerbus, I am a complete newbie could you please help or direct me.

Comment: I couldn't. This is just what I got from reading the documentation, I've never even installed AHK.

Comment: All right, I'll try figuring it out but not sure if I'd be able to as I've just installed AHK and don't know much about scripting!